# How to include css pie in Rails 3.2 with asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, css, asset-pipeline, css3pie

I would like to include PIE.htc in my Rails application to make CSS3 easier for IE. I can't seem to figure out how to include the PIE.htc file.

I tried to include PIE.htc in my assets folder as well as assets/stylesheets folder, but I no routes matching error.

How do I include PIE.htc with rails asset pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution in this post: [Using PIE.htc in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483371/using-pie-htc-in-rails)

Basically, it should be:

```
behavior: url(/assets/PIE.htc);
```

Also, if you want to be completely sure that the PIE.htc file is being loaded, open it and add an alert as so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("PIE works);
```

If the file if being loaded, a popup should appear showing the message.

Comment: Using `asset_url` is probably an even better idea, so `behavior: asset-url(PIE.htc)` if you're using asset pipeline.